# file upload in jpeg(jpg), gif, doc, docx, rtf, xml, tiff, pdf, html(htm), png and bmp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Is there any directive or any other way where I can check if an uploaded file is password protected or not with common code(JavaScript)?

I want to this condition on file upload in angular.

Below is HTML

```
 <button class="bg-green c-btn btn" ngf-select="corrLoanDocuments.onFileSelect($files)">
                                                Browse</button>
```

Comment: Which technology you are using in backend

Comment: Backend code is written in c#. but i want it to check in angular

Comment: Yes, You can do this in angular or angularjs using library https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfreader

Comment: i want common code for all types of files and my exact question is how can i find the file is password protected or no

Comment: First, you need to know that how you can achieve it? and what exactly password protection is and how our file system achieving this one.

Comment: This is not the big Issue you may either do it on client end or server convert your file to blob and you are good to what you want to acheive

Comment: Yes i can do that but that is not my question. i want to check it in client side so is that possible ??

Comment: Simply! Yes, Possible

Comment: please give working example.